# Extract frequency value from last column depending on what letter is there to plot

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a tab-delimited file that has frequency values in the last column (actually the values are tab-delimited as well). I have mostly two values (e.g., A:0  G:1) but some rows have three values (e.g., G:0  C:1  A:0)

```
CHROM   POS N_ALLELES   N_CHR   {ALLELE:FREQ}

NC_037638.1 355689  2   2   A:0 G:1

NC_037638.1 355694  2   2   G:0.5   A:0.5

NC_037638.1 355703  2   2   C:0.5   G:0.5

NC_037638.1 355706  2   2   T:0.5   C:0.5

NC_037638.1 355715  2   2   A:0.5   G:0.5

NC_037638.1 355794  3   1   G:0 C:1 A:0

NC_037638.1 355723  2   2   A:0 G:1

NC_037638.1 355732  2   2   C:0.5   T:0.5

.

.

.
```

I want to extract the frequency values as new columns for each row depending on what letter is there out of four (A,C,G,T). My desired output is something like this:

```
CHROM   POS N_ALLELES   N_CHR   A_FREQ G_FREQ C_FREQ T_FREQ

NC_037638.1 355689  2   2   0   1   NA   NA

NC_037638.1 355694  2   2   0.5  0.5  NA  NA

NC_037638.1 355703  2   2   NA  0.5  0.5  NA

NC_037638.1 355706  2   2   NA   NA  0.5  0.5

NC_037638.1 355715  2   2   0.5 0.5  NA NA

NC_037638.1 355794  3   1   0   0  1  NA

NC_037638.1 355723  2   2   0   1  NA  NA

NC_037638.1 355732  2   2   NA  NA  0.5 0.5

.

.

.
```

If I have the frequency values in the columns then I can easily plot in R or something. 'NA' is desired but could be just missing values or even 0. I am mostly concerned about how to remove the colon and put the values into columns.

An alternate solution could be if someone can suggest to me how to plot the frequency of each base (A,T,G,C) at each POS in R or Excel without having to worry about transforming it into columns.

I tried different solutions and struggled with plotting but all in vain. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated to perform this in bash/R/Python. Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
$ cat file
CHROM   POS     N_ALLELES       N_CHR   {ALLELE:FREQ}
NC_037638.1     355689  2       2       A:0     G:1
NC_037638.1     355694  2       2       G:0.5   A:0.5
NC_037638.1     355703  2       2       C:0.5   G:0.5
NC_037638.1     355706  2       2       T:0.5   C:0.5
NC_037638.1     355715  2       2       A:0.5   G:0.5
NC_037638.1     355794  3       1       G:0     C:1     A:0
NC_037638.1     355723  2       2       A:0     G:1
NC_037638.1     355732  2       2       C:0.5   T:0.5
```

then

```
$ awk '
  BEGIN{
    split("A:G:C:T",allele,/:/); OFS="\t"
  }
  NR==1 {
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,"A_FREQ","G_FREQ","C_FREQ","T_FREQ"; next
  } 
  {
    for(i=5;i<=NF;i++){
      split($i,a,/:/); freq[a[1]]=a[2]
    }
  } 
  {
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
      $(i+4) = allele[i] in freq ? freq[allele[i]] : "NA"
    }
    delete freq
  } 
  1
' file
CHROM   POS     N_ALLELES       N_CHR   A_FREQ  G_FREQ  C_FREQ  T_FREQ
NC_037638.1     355689  2       2       0       1       NA      NA
NC_037638.1     355694  2       2       0.5     0.5     NA      NA
NC_037638.1     355703  2       2       NA      0.5     0.5     NA
NC_037638.1     355706  2       2       NA      NA      0.5     0.5
NC_037638.1     355715  2       2       0.5     0.5     NA      NA
NC_037638.1     355794  3       1       0       0       1       NA
NC_037638.1     355723  2       2       0       1       NA      NA
NC_037638.1     355732  2       2       NA      NA      0.5     0.5
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code. I am getting all 'NA'. My head(Input file):
CHROM POS N_ALLELES N_CHR {ALLELE:FREQ}
NC_037638.1 3536 2 2 G:0 A:1
NC_037638.1 3540 2 2 T:0 C:1
NC_037638.1 3556 2 2 G:0 A:1
NC_037638.1 3560 2 2 T:0 C:1

head(outputfile):
CHROM POS N_ALLELES N_CHR A_FREQ G_FREQ C_FREQ T_FREQ
NC_037638.1 3536 2 2 NA NA NA NA
NC_037638.1 3540 2 2 NA NA NA NA
NC_037638.1 3556 2 2 NA NA NA NA
NC_037638.1 3560 2 2 NA NA NA NA

Comment: @DonUltimate is your awk `mawk` or `gawk`? it seems that mawk doesn't allow an empty regex to split the initial `AGCT` into characters - if you are using mawk, it should work if you change the split in the `BEGIN` block to `split("A:G:C:T",allele,/:/)` (or really any other delimiter).

Comment: ... I've edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, it is mawk and it worked like a charm!!